# Magento 2.3.2 Check Files For Modifications

Tags: magento2

Is there any way to check your install for core files that may have been modified, miss-copied, or just don't belong?

I have a bug that keeps rearing its head and I want to make sure that a "core" file of the stock magento component has not been accidentally modified or damaged. I know wordpress has functionality to this effect but I am struggling to find something for Magento 2.

Is there a tool to compare/inspect the files and look for anything out of place?

Kind Regards
James

Answer (score 0):

Nothing Magento provides does this, though it would be nice if it did! Doesn't mean it can't be done though, but it will be a manual check. You could try one of these options:

- If version control was used to deploy, check for changes (assuming this isn't the case or you probably wouldn't be asking)
- Re-deploy, with fresh files
- Checksum core code directories (https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/35832/how-do-i-get-the-md5-sum-of-a-directorys-contents-as-one-sum) and checksum core code directions from directly downloaded same version package from Magento. Compare these checksums.